# Custom directive`s scope doesn't pass to child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Sorry if I duplicate existing post, but I search SO on the subject and couldn't find description for my case.

I got a custom directive (carousel) that contain inner directives (slides)
Carousel directive receives the scope, but I don't manage to pass (or make) the Slides directive to understand the scope.

If I take outside inner directive, the slides see and understand the scope. But if I contain the slides inside the carousel, they loose it, and do not get nothing.

Anyone with idea what im doing wrong?

```
# Carousel Directive
define ['app'], (app) ->
    app.directive 'carousel', ->
        return {} =
        restrict: 'E'
        templateUrl: window.templateDir + 'carousel.html'
        replace: true
        scope:
            photo: '='
            leftSwipeAction: '&'
            rightSwipeAction: '&'
            clickAction: '&'
        link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
            #....

# Slides Directive
define ['app'], (app) ->
    app.directive 'preview', ->
        return {} =
            restrict: 'E'
            templateUrl: window.templateDir + 'preview.html'
            replace: true
            scope:
                photo: '='
                leftSwipeAction: '&'
                rightSwipeAction: '&'
                clickAction: '&'
            link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
                element.bind 'error', ->
                    element[0].src = scope.photo.download()
                element.bind 'dragstart', (e) ->
                    e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Can you post your templates, please? Even better, can you post a working fiddle or Plnkr?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @CaioToOn. I just discovered that by defining my scope like that, i limiting it to directive scope only, and scope stops passing to any inner directive child. I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that by defining my scope like that, i limiting it to directive scope to the directive only, and scope stops passing to any inner directive child.

I deleted the scopes configuration and now its accessible to all directives. Even nested ones.